# Writing the column headers with specific values using comma delimiters to a separate column

Tags: python, excel, database, excel-formula

[image]

I have a set of images with multiple labels. The presence is denoted by 1 and the absence by 0 or no value. I have to write the column headers whose values are 1, comma delimited, to a separate column called 'Genre'. An example is shown for image '1.png'. Is there a formula in excel to do this?

Comment: Yes TEXTJOIN if you have it, otherwise it will take code.

Comment: @ScottCraner: Could you please help with the syntax for the same, for the given example? Thanks.

Comment: I tried =TEXTJOIN(“,”,TRUE,B2:J2) but it throws an error. B2 to J2 is the range of input columns (from cat to train). I have to write only those columns whose values are 1, as shown for image "1.png".

Comment: You need to use this syntax. `=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(B2:J2=1,B2:J2,""))`, and confirm the formula as an array formula, with SHIFT+CTL+ENTER.

Comment: @Variatus: Thanks. If I use the syntax you suggest, it is writing [1,1,1, 1] instead of writing the column headers like ['Cat', 'Tree', 'Sand', 'Bus'] as shown for example 1.png. Also I tried modifying tunction as =TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(B2:J2=1,B1:J1,"")) to write the column headers B1:J1 if B2:J2=1. However, when I drop down the formula, the B1:J1 changes to B2:J2, B3:J3, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the formula below on a replica of your worksheet. It works even when entered as a normal formula.

=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF($B2:$J2=1,$B$1:$J$1,""))

Working as a normal or array formula is most likely a matter of Excel version. Different versions may return different results. I tested on Excel 365. The result you got seems to show that you didn't enter the formula with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Observe that I added a space after the comma. You can remove it if you just want a CSV string.

When you copy formulas you must always check the $ signs they contain to ensure that the changes Excel makes are those that you want.